# How to identify contours within another contour using JavaCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, javacv

How to identify contours within another contour? I tried to go through many OpenCV tutorials but I was unable to identify it. Please can some expert person provide simple code to explain it?

This is my input file

[image]

This dark part is the contour that I need to identify.

[image]

Please be kind enough to share your experience with me.

Comment: Can you provide more info? What is the criteria of detection that filled contour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple approach in Python code. (`But as I stated in my comment below, It is not an universal answer applicable everywhere, It is just to show finding contour inside a contour can be done. And if your images are different, then you have to come with some different constraints other than i mentioned below`)

What you are doing after finding Contours is that, you check if area of each contour is less than a specified value ( i gave 10000, just a guess), if not it is bigger contour, avoid it. If less than specified value, it may be our square or rectangle next to it.

So we find its width and height and check if aspect ratio close to 1. if so, it is our square.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sofcnt.jpg')
gray = cv2.imread('sofcnt.jpg',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

cont,hier = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in cont:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 10000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if w/float(h) < 2:
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,255,-1)


cv2.imshow('a',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that similar to square figure inside some ploygon is needed figure? Maybe author wants to find a figure that contains center of some pologon? Thanks.

Comment: +1 - Yeah, you are right, then he has to specify that too. I think he wanted to see how to identify any contour within a contour, so this is one type to do so. this way he has to find other solution, and ofcourse it is not an universal answer, only for this particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not very comfortable with JavaCV, so here's how I went about solving this problem in OpenCV and C (ancient stuff):

1. Find all the contours in the image using the `cvFindContours()`
2. Run two loops (iterate pointers `h_next` or whatever is there in JavaCV) over these contours. For each contour in the outer loop, match it with every other contour detected based on . . .
3. Calculate bounding box of each contour. This will be a `CvRect` structure.
4. Pass the two `CvRects` to a function that calculates the area of intersection (overlap) between two rectangles.
5. If this area is equal to area of the smaller of the two rectangles, then the contour corresponding to the smaller rectangle is completely enclosed by the larger one.

   Here's the code for finding the area of intersection. It must have been floating around the web somewhere.

   `CvRect intersect(CvRect r1, CvRect r2)
   {
       CvRect intersection;`

   ```
   // find overlapping region
   intersection.x = (r1.x < r2.x) ? r2.x : r1.x;
   intersection.y = (r1.y < r2.y) ? r2.y : r1.y;
   intersection.width = (r1.x + r1.width < r2.x + r2.width) ?
       r1.x + r1.width : r2.x + r2.width;
   intersection.width -= intersection.x;
   intersection.height = (r1.y + r1.height < r2.y + r2.height) ?
       r1.y + r1.height : r2.y + r2.height;
   intersection.height -= intersection.y;    

   // check for non-overlapping regions
   if ((intersection.width <= 0) || (intersection.height <= 0)) {
       intersection = cvRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
   }

   return intersection;
   ```

   `}`